# Warning message on lightning new record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, warning

I want to show a warning message on lightning standard record creation page. If that is not possible is there a way to create a lightning component with all fields on standard page layout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all dependent on what you are trying to achieve because I'd say using the standard layout is always the way to go unless you have a deal-breaker requirement.

1. If this is for validation on data they're entering - use validation
   rules
2. If this is to serve as some sort of reminder before they even start
   filling out values - consider just adding a read-only field that you
   can put at the top that states this.

For point #2, it can even include an Image if you want it to be more visually prominent as noted [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327122&type=1&mode=1). Any text field that is *read only* can have a **"default" value** to get a point across if that's all that is needed.

Otherwise, I'd say creating a lightning component for this does not seem like a good reason to go this route. However, just to answer the question - there is the [record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) or [record-view-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation).